# The Commit of directory is same as the one of Root Folder

Tags: git, github-actions

I am trying to match commits between root folder and subfolder to identify the change in folder.

I am using git log to get the commit ID of root folder with

```
git log --pretty=tformat:"%H" -n 1 -- .
```

And to get the commit ID of subfolder

```
git log --pretty=tformat:"%H" -n 1 --  functions/function1
```

**This works absolutely fine on my local but as soon as I deploy it to Github actions and call with a run.sh file with command it gives same commit for root folder and subfolder.**

```
bash run.sh
```

I am checking out the same branch in github action with -

```
- name: 'Checkout GitHub Action'
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
      ref: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_branch }}
```

Anybody has any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it just after posting the question

I got the issues with Github Actions.
**actions/checkout@v3** fetches only the last commit and applies it to all the files which I saw with

```
git show --pretty="" --name-only $hash
```

After checking their [documentation](https://github.com/actions/checkout) I had to change my action to fetch all history with

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
  fetch-depth: 0
```

**The fetch-depth: 0** solved my problem